# REXX program that will show a task from DA with the highest CPU usage

Tags: mainframe, zos, rexx, sdsf

i'm quite new to programming with REXX. I'd like to write a program that will show a task from DA with the biggest CPU usage on the LPAR. Thanks in advance

```
000001 /* rexx */                                             
000002 RC=ISFCALLS('ON')                                      
000003 isfcols = "JNAME CPUPR JTYPE"                          
000004       /*Access the DA panel */                         
000005 ADDRESS SDSF "ISFEXEC DA"                              
000006 IF RC<>0 THEN                                          
000007   EXIT RC                                              
000008      /* GET FIXED FIELD NAME FROM FIRST WORD */        
000009      /*OF ISFCOLS SPECIAL VARIABLE           */        
000010 fixedField = word(isfcols,1)                           
000011 Say "Number of rows returned:" isfrows                 
000012        /* Process all rows */                          
000013 do ix=1 to isfrows                                     
000014   Say "Now processing job:" value(fixedField"."ix)     
000015           /* List all columns for row */              
000016  do jx=1 to words(isfcols)                                
000017    col = word(isfcols,jx)                                 
000018    say " Column" col"."ix "has the value:" value(col"."ix)
000019  end                                                      
000020 end                                                       
000021 rc=isfcalls('OFF')
```

I'm not sure if I started correctly, I'm reviewing Redbook to find some answers, but it's a little bit rough. Could someone advice me on that? I managed to specify colums which I would like to see, but still can't get to the point where it will return me only the task with highest CPU. I assume that I have to specify sth on line 13 just to search highest number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of special variables which are used to custpmize what, and how you want SDSF to return data. You're already using `ISFCOLS` to specify which colums you need.

To get the row for the ASID (*) using the most CPU in this snapshot as the first row, tell SDSF to sort the data returned by descending CPU% value. Add the following line anywhere before calling SDSF:

```
isfsort="CPUPR D"
```

See [Using special variables to invoke SDSF function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=language-using-special-variables-invoke-sdsf-function), and specifically table [Special variables reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=reference-special-variables#xvarrefx) in the SDSF manual for a list of all special variables.

(*) A note on terminology: SDSF lists data for *Address Spaces* (ASID), not tasks. There are a number of *tasks* running in each address space. With SDSF, you get the total usage per *Address Space*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I made some changes and it's working. I also appreciate the links that you added, they helped me to get a better overview at what exactly I'm doing or try to do.